# AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete event not firing when passing query string for the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using `AjaxFileUpload1` of Ajax control toolkit.

I am passing query string to page where i am using `AjaxFileUpload1` control

(Say for example for page WebForm1.aspx?Key=22)

But problem here is if i pass query string to WebForm1.aspx page
that time

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
```

this event is not firing

Can any one help me for this..

Thanks in advance...
Regards,
**Prasad**

Comment: You are saying that it works when you call it without parameter, for example `Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx")` but not with parameter, for example `Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?Key=22")`? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Tim Schmelter  ... but im facing same problem here...

Answer (score 2):

### SOLVED!

Googling carefully I found that [AJAX Control Toolkit Release Notes - September 2012  Release](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/94873) says:

> Finally, we integrated several Pull Requests contributed by the community:
>
> Resolved an issue which prevented the AjaxFileUpload control from working with pages that require query string variables.

so the problem is solved using last version of Ajax Control Toolkit.